Cones of divisors on cyclic covers
I am learning about cyclic covers and here are a few preliminary calculations. I would really appreciate it if someone could kindly check if they are correct, and any comments are appreciated,

Let $f:X\to Y$ be an $n$-fold cyclic cover of smooth projective surfaces, branched over $B$. Hence, $B$ is smooth as well. Projection formula gives us,
$$H^i(X,\mathcal{O}_X)=H^i(Y,f_*\mathcal{O}_X)$$
In particular, if we have a double cover, then,
$$H^i(X,\mathcal{O}_X)=H^i(Y,\mathcal{O}_Y\oplus L^{-1})=H^i(Y,\mathcal{O}_Y)\oplus H^i(Y,L^{-1}),$$
where $B=\operatorname{div}(s)$ for some section $s$ of $L$. Hence, if $h^1(Y,L^{-1})=0$, then,
$$q(Y)=0\implies q(X)=0.$$
Let $f:X\to Y$ be an $n$-fold cyclic cover of smooth projective surfaces. If $D$ is nef on $Y$, $C$ is an integral curve on $X$, then, $f^*D\cdot C=D\cdot f_*C\geq 0$. Thus,
$$f^*(\operatorname{Nef}Y)\subseteq \operatorname{Nef}X$$
Now, if $D$ is a divisor on $X$, then $f^*(f_*D)=nD \implies f^*(\frac{1}{n}f^*D)=D.$ Hence,
$$\operatorname{Nef}X\subseteq f^*\operatorname{Nef}Y$$
Thus, we get,
$$f^*\operatorname{Nef}Y=\operatorname{Nef}X.$$
Since, the dual of the nef cone $\operatorname{Nef}X$ is $\overline{\operatorname{Eff}}X$, can we relate $f^*(\overline{\operatorname{Eff}}Y)$ and $\overline{\operatorname{Eff}}X$ as well?
In general, is there a nice description of the Picard group of $X$ if we know $\operatorname{Pic}Y$ well enough? If not in general, what about in the case of double covers? What are the generators of $\operatorname{Pic}X$ in this case?
Lastly, does anyone know anything about the ample cone of $X$, where $f:X\to Y$ is a double cover?

P.S: I am asking all this for the case when $B$ is smooth. So, both $X$ and $Y$ are smooth projective surfaces.

It is not true that $f^*(f_*D) = 2D$. For example, consider the (cyclic) double covering $\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1 \to \mathbb{P}^2$. If you take $D$ to be a ruling then the left side is the sum of two different rulings, which is not the same as twice the ruling.

As a more extreme example of what Sasha refers to, if $X$ is a del Pezzo surface of degree 2 then it has a double cover $X \rightarrow \mathbf P^2$. Here $\operatorname{Pic}(X) = \mathbf Z^8$ while $\operatorname{Pic}(Y)=\mathbf Z$; the ample cone of $Y$ is just a half-line in $\mathbf R$ while the ample cone of $X$ is (the interior of) a complicated polyhedral cone.

@LazzaroCampeotti: An even more extreme example is a double covering (branched at sextic) of the plane by a K3 surface $X$, here the Picard rank of $X$ can go up to 20. And taking the branch divisors of higher degree, you can probably find even more extreme examples.

@Sasha, thanks for the examples. So in general we only have $f^*(\operatorname{Nef}Y)\subseteq \operatorname{Nef} X$. Is there any condition that gurantees the reverse direction as well? Also, any idea how hard it would be to calculate the nef cone of a double cover? Given $B$ is smooth.
